# A base64 encoding is returning None from the .bash_profile where I save it as an Environment variable

Tags: python, bash

I saved a base64 encoding as as an environment variable in .bash_profile

.bash_profile

```
export ENCODED_JSON="b'Aewe323'"
```

doing the following in a python script returns None

```
import os
ENCODED_JSON = os.environ.get('ENCODED_JSON')
print(ENCODED_JSON)
```

Comment: Did you reload .bash_profile after editing it? Like `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: yes, and I closed my visual studio code and reopened after the change

Comment: try it in `.bashrc`

Comment: *~/.bash_profile* is only read by interactive login shells. Your python code is telling you that file wasn't sourced by your current shell or any of its parent shells.